# How to import friends from Parse Cloud and Add them to a ArrayList

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to view friends list in `AlertDialog` with `MultiChoiceMode`. As I see I can add array to `AlertDialog.setMultiChoiceMode` how can I work around with this?

```
mFriendsRelation = user.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

    }
});
new AlertDialog.Builder(SingleVideoView.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_forever_grey600_36dp)
        .setMessage("Share this video with all your friends")
        .setMultiChoiceItems()
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
```

Comment: at done method you get objects array this is add at your custom arraylist

Comment: @HardikParmar I have tried that but this doesn't work with setMultiChoiceItems

Comment: what meaning of setMultiChoiceItems ???

Comment: @HardikParmar it uses Charsequence array

Comment: check in done method what you get in array how many items u fetching ?